# Javascript Prompt Validation?

Tags: javascript, validation, switch-statement, conditional-statements, prompt

I want to prompt the user to enter a sport (baseball, football, soccer, or track). Let's say I enter "Golf". How do I get it to keep asking me to enter a sport until I enter one of the valid sports? The sport determines what field they play on. Below is my code.

```
var sport = prompt("What sport do you play? (Baseball, Football, Soccer, or Track)").toLowerCase (); 

switch (sport) {
    case "baseball": 
        field = "Field 1";
        break;
    case "football": 
        field = "Field 2";
        break;
    case "soccer":
        field = "Field 3";
        break;
    case "track":
        field = "Field 4";
        break;
    default: alert("Please enter a valid sport");
}
```

Comment: What if I'm trying to do the same thing for a range age groups. I want to prompt the user to enter their age . Let's say they are between the age of 5 - 9 or an age range of 10 - 15. How do I get it to keep asking me to enter an age until I enter one of the valid ages? The age determines what time they play. Below is my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
loop:
while(true){
    var sport = prompt("What sport do you play? (Baseball, Football, Soccer, or Track)").toLowerCase(); 
    switch (sport) {
        case "baseball": 
            field = "Field 1";
            break loop;
        case "football": 
            field = "Field 2";
            break loop;
        case "soccer":
            field = "Field 3";
            break loop;
        case "track":
            field = "Field 4";
            break loop;
        default: alert("Please enter a valid sport");
    }
}
```

or

```
var field;
while(true){
    var sport = prompt("What sport do you play? (Baseball, Football, Soccer, or Track)").toLowerCase();
    if(!sport || /^(baseball|football|soccer|track)$/.test(sport)){
        field = "Field " + ("baseball|football|soccer|track".split("|").indexOf(sport)+1);
        break;
    }else{
        alert("Please enter a valid sport");
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude you're awesome thank you! I have another question. Lets say I'm trying to do the same thing for age.

Comment: Below is my code.

var age = prompt("How old are you?"); var practiceTime = age;

if (age > 15) { practiceTime = "6:00 pm"; } else if (age > 12) { practiceTime = "5:00 pm"; } else if (age > 9) { practiceTime = "4:00 pm"; } else if (age > 4) { practiceTime = "3:00 pm"; 
} else if (isNaN(age)) { alert(age + " " + "is not a valid age. Please enter a valid age."); }

Comment: @user3538369 - It would be done the same way as in my code sample. Use a `while` loop, and `break` it when the user entered a valid input.

Comment: I can't figure out the syntax for something like this example loop:
while(true){
    var age = prompt("Pleae enter your age"); 
    switch (age) {
        case age < 15  && age > 10: 
            practiceTime = "6:00 pm";
            break loop;