# Validate prompt javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code, I need validate the prompt to only accept letters, not numbers, not blank spaces, not characters, any sugestions ???

```js
nombre = prompt("Ingrese su nombre");
switch(nombre)
{
    case "pedro" : 
        alert("Hola pedro");
    break;
    case "juan" : 
        alert("Hola juan");
    break;
    case "diego" : 
        alert("Hola diego");
    break;
    default : 
        alert("Hola Desconocido"); 
    break;
}
alert("Fin");
```

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097859/javascript-prompt-validation

Comment: @tresh_03... there is no functionality to validate to enter only numeric value with prompt default function of JavaScript. you can only get entered value in prompt in response then based on input you can validate or show error message otherwise there is no predefined functionality for numeric entry only.

Answer (score 0):

Google 'js regex example'  - you're looking for something like

```
if(!/^[A-Za-z]*$/.exec(nombre)){
  //que mal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var validatior = function (v) {
        var t = /^[a-zA-Z_\- ]+$/;
        return t.test(v);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression test would be easiest:

```
var re = /[^A-Za-z]/;
var nombre;

do {
  nombre = prompt("Ingrese su nombre");
} while(re.test(nombre))

// rest of code...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to test for non-english letters as well you can do something like this

```
var containsOnlyletter = /^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00ff]+$/.test(myStr)
```