# How to detect a invalid prompt answer?

Tags: javascript, prompt

Example of what I am trying to achieve:

```js
var p = prompt("What is your favorite number?", 1, 2, 3, 4);
if (p) {
  function checkForInvalid() {
    const invalid = "invalid"
  }
}
if (p === invalid) {
  alert("Sorry, I don't know that number");
}
```

or something similar. I am relatively new to javascript.
Could I use a function to check if the number is not specified within the prompt? I am not trying to validate anything...

Comment: I would recommend working through a book on js, for example https://javascript.info/ is a great free book.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Prompt Validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097859/javascript-prompt-validation)

Comment: @chiliNUT It does not...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```js
const validNumbers = [1,2,3,4];

var p = prompt("What is your favorite number?", validNumbers[0]);

if (validNumbers.indexOf(Number(p)) == -1) {
  alert("Sorry, I don't know that number");
}
```

Comment: `prompt` returns a string, and `[1,2,3,4].indexOf(SomeString)` will always be `-1`

Comment: @Christian Fritz When running your code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8s1fobku/), the alert would always show up. Maybe add an `else` ?

Comment: ah, sorry, was missing a cast to Number. Now it's working as expected.